# Why is heap well suited for merging sorted streams?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

I was reading some algorithms book and came across this line,

```
Heaps are well suited for algorithms that merge sorted data streams.
```

There wasn't any explanation given about why is that the case. Could someone please help me explain why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have two data streams then you really don't need a heap as the following algorithm will do:

```
Let s1 ans s2 be the two streams

while s1.hasData() and s2.hasData()
    if s1.peek() < s2.peek(): datum = s1.pop()
    else: datum = s2.pop()
    s.push(datum)
if either is non-empty (only one is), add the rest of its content to s
```

As pointed out by Henk Holterman, if you have `k>2` streams, then you achieve the merging via heap (essentially the heap does the now-complicated decision of which stream to use in the current step):

```
let H be a (min  or max, depending on your needs) heap
let s1, s2, ..., sk be sorted streams

// fill the heap with the first elements from the streams (e.g. min/max elements from each stream, depending on how they're sorted)
for i=1 to k:
    H.add((i, si.pop())) // we need to know which stream the element came from

let s be the initially-empty data stream which will contain the merged content in sorted order
// H.empty() will indicate that all streams are empty
while not H.empty():
    // take the min/max element of the min/max elements of each stream (*the* min/max element)
    (i, datum) = H.extract()
    // add it to s
    s.push(datum)
    // we know the datum came from s[i]; thus we need to push the next element from the i-th stream into heap as it may contain the next min/max element (that is, if s[i] isn't empty)
    if not s[i].empty():
        // we'll assume the heap sorts based on the second component of the pair
        H.add((i, s[i].pop())
// s is the sorted stream containing elements from s1,s2,...,sk
```

This running time of this is `O((|s1|+...+|sk|) * log k)`, where `|si|` denotes the number of elements in the stream `si`.

The key idea is that in each iteration of the `while`-loop you add the smallest/largest of `s[1].peek()`, `s[2].peek()`, ..., `s[k].peek()` to `s`. You achieve this using heap which tells you which stream currently contains the smallest/largest element. And notice how the edge case of a stream being empty is handled elegantly.

Comment: But how will `s1.peek() < s2.peek()` look when merging 20 streams?

Comment: Ah, yes, in general you do need a heap.

Comment: Thanks for the response, blazs! One question though, why heap is well suited for this? Why not binary search tree for instance? I apologize in advance if it is a really naive question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Heap is a natural choice because it maintains the min/max element of the elements in the structure; and adding/extracting is relatively cheap (guaranteed to be O(log n) where n=# of elements in the heap).

Comment: You could use, say, a balanced binary search tree, but the latter would maintain additional invariants that are really not needed for this task. Heap is, I believe, more efficient (internally it's usually represented as a simple array; see the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation)).

Comment: `but the latter would maintain additional invariants that are really not needed for this task` 
Not sure I understand this. :( What are these additional invariants?

Comment: Well, the BST guarantees that for each internal node `n`, all keys stored at the subtree rooted at `n.left` are smaller than or equal to `n.key` while all keys stored at the subtree rooted at `n.right` are greater than `n.key`. Additionally, of the BST is balanced (e.g. red-black tree), then there is an additional requirement that the subtrees be reasonably balanced, so that the depth is kept `O(log n)` where `n = #elements in the tree)`; low depth guarantees efficient operations.

Comment: Notice how this partial-order requirement is a stronger condition that what you have in the case of heap, where, if you do array-based implementation, you only want that for each `i`, the element `A[i] >= max(A[2i], A[2i+1])` (this is in case of the max heap).

Comment: This is starting to make sense now. Thanks for explaining this. I am still not sure about the code you have provided though. Is it at all possible for you to add a bit more explanatory comments to help me understand that? I'd really appreciate it. Specifically, I am not sure what you are adding to heap and these particular comments `essentially the heap does the now-complicated condition of which stream to use in the current step` and `we need to know which stream the element came from`. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: I've added some additional comments and an explanation after the pseudo code. I hope it helps. Feel free to ask for further clarification.